# polymer class binding inside dom-repeat not working

Tags: binding, polymer-1.0, dom-repeat

I'm trying to bind a computed value to an element inside a dom-repeat template.

```
<iron-selector class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
      <div class$="item {{_itemClass(selectedItems)}}" data-value="[[item]]" on-click="_onItemClick">[[item]]</div>
   </template>
</iron-selector>
```

My goal here is to update the dropdown items styling when the user selects one of them. When this happens, I update the `selectedItems` array by pushing the item value to it. This will trigger the rendering of the selection box but will fail to call the `_itemClass(selectedItems)` expression.

What am I missing here? I read in the documentation that you must specify the properties that will trigger the binding and I'm doing that by adding the `selectedItems` to the binding expression with no luck at all.

I attached a snippet with the current behaviour.

Any help will be welcome.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- polygit -->
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/"> <!-- saves typing! -->
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-dropdown/iron-dropdown.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
  <!-- style -->
  <style>
    x-example {
      width: 250px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<x-example></x-example>
  
<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment"></style>
  <style>
    :host {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .body {
      @apply --layout-horizontal;
    }

    .body .selection {
      border: 1px solid green;
      margin: 2px;
      flex-grow: 1
    }

    .body .selection .item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 2px;
      background: lightgreen;
      padding: 2px 5px;
      border: 1px solid green;
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: darkblue;
    }

    .body .selection .item .text {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .body .selection .item iron-icon {
      width: 18px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .body .dropdown {
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      margin: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      min-height: 40px;
    }

    .body .dropdown iron-icon {
      margin: auto;
    }

    .options iron-dropdown {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 6px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .options .item {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    iron-selector>* {
      padding: 8px;
      background: aqua;
    }

    .horizontal-section {
      padding: 0;
    }

    .iron-selected {
      background-color: var(--google-blue-500);
      color: white;
    }
    
  </style>
  <template>
 
        <div class="body">
            <div class="flex selection">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[selectedItems]]">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="text">[[item]]</div>
                        <iron-icon class="dropdown-trigger" icon="icons:clear" on-click="_onRemoveItem"></iron-icon>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown" on-click="_toggleDropdown">
                <iron-icon icon="icons:arrow-drop-down"></iron-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="options">
            <iron-dropdown auto-fit-on-attach="true" id="dropdown" horizontal-align="left" vertical-align="top">
                <iron-selector class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
                        <div class$="item {{_itemClass(selectedItems)}}" data-value="[[item]]" on-click="_onItemClick">[[item]]</div>
                    </template>
                </iron-selector>
            </iron-dropdown>
        </div>
    
  </template>
  <script>
    
    // only need this when both (1) in the main document and (2) on non-Chrome browsers
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      
      Polymer({
        is: "x-example",
        properties: {
          items: {
            type: Array,
            value: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
          },
          selectedItems: {
            type: Array,
            value: []
          }
        },
        _toggleDropdown: function() {
          this.$.dropdown.toggle();
        },
        _onItemClick: function(e) {
          var value = e.srcElement.dataValue;
          if (this.selectedItems.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
            return;
          }
          this.push("selectedItems", value)
          this._refreshDropdown();
        },
        _refreshDropdown: function() {
          this.async(function() {
            this.$.dropdown.position();
          })
        },
        _onRemoveItem(e) {
          let index = this.selectedItems.indexOf(e.srcElement.dataValue);
          this.splice("selectedItems", index, 1);
          this._refreshDropdown();
        },
        _itemClass: function() {
          console.log("item class called")
        }
        
      });
      
    });
    
  </script>
</dom-module>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is `_itemClass(selectedItems)` which only triggers when the variable selectedItems changes, not when the array mutates.

You've got two options:

1) Either change your binding to `_itemClass(selectedItems.*)`, which will get triggered by `this.push` and other array mutating methods

2) Change the variable each time:

```
this.set('selectedItems', [].concat(this.selectedItems).concat(value));
```

A working example with the first solution (and 2nd solution commented out) is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2q3fqehz/114/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your issue, but I'm using a similar pattern myself. My guess is that Polymer isn't supporting declaration of a class and a bound class within the same tag.

I use attributes and attribute selectors instead, which works just as expected.

Can you try to change the class to an attribute and style based on attribute selectors? Here is the relevant code:

```
<style>

.item[selected] {
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

...

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
  <div class="item" selected$="[[_computeSelected]]" on-tap="_onItemTap">[[item]]</div>
</template>


_onItemTap: function(event) {
  const item = event.model.item;
},

_computeSelected: function(item) (
  return yourSelectionLogic ? true : false;
}
```

Two other notes: Use on-tap instead of on-click. It makes mobile touch events normalized with desktop events. Also, you don't need to bind the data value for each item as it is included through the tap-event when it is triggered within a dom-repeat.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your tips on the tap events and the data value that goes as an argument.  
Binding to class attribute is documented [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#compound-bindings) so I'm assuming this is possible. 
I tried to do as you described but the `selected$` attribute is only computed on the first iteration. I want it to be dynamic. So as I am changing the selection the value gets computed. This is still not working.

Comment: In that case, your cleanest option is probably to update the underlying data in your items array. This will trigger a new computation. That way, you'll have one source of truth.

Comment: "_My guess is that Polymer isn't supporting declaration of a class and a bound class within the same tag._"

This case falls under [compound bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#compound-bindings) and is supported by Polymer.